# I need to fetch data from a JSON object saved in my component.ts file

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I need to fetch data from a JSON object saved in my `component.ts` file.

```
Object_name=[
    {"name": "value_1","prop":["data_1","data_2","data_3"]},
    {"name": "value_2","prop":["data_1","data_2","data_3"]},
    {"name": "value_3","prop":["data_1","data_2","data_3"]}
];
```

I want to fetch object_name and check if(value_1) then get data of "prop" in any variable or console.
I am new in angular please share your answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your `Object_name` array

```
const filtered = Object_name.filter(item => item.name === 'value_1');
filtered.forEach(item => console.log(item.prop));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.Object_name.length; i++) {
    if(this.Object_name[i].name == "value_1") {
      console.log(this.Object_name[i].prop)
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide an answer to the question, we prefer answers with some explanation as to how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use for in loop

```
for (const key in this.Object_name) {
    if (this.Object_name[key].name == 'value_1' ){      
       console.log(this.Object_name[key].prop);
    }   
}
```